# Execute SQL in Doctrine Fixtures Symfony 4

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I want insert some Sql code into database by Doctrine Fixtures. Here's my class.

```
class ProvinceFixtures extends BaseFixtures
{
    public function loadData(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $sql = '
            INSERT INTO `province` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
                (1, \'TP Đà Nẵng\', \'2019-07-09 08:45:02\', \'2019-07-09 08:45:02\'),
                (2, \'TP Hà Nội\', \'2019-07-09 08:45:02\', \'2019-07-09 08:45:02\'),
                (3, \'TP Hải Phòng\', \'2019-07-09 08:45:02\', \'2019-07-09 08:45:02\');
        ';

        /* @var EntityManagerInterface $manager */
        $manager->getConnection()->exec($sql);

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

But when I run `doctrine:fixtures:load`, my Terminal show this log.

```
Call to an undefined method Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager::getConnection().
```

How can I fix that. Thank you.

*Update: `BaseFixture` class

```
abstract class BaseFixtures extends Fixture
{
    /** @var Generator */
    protected $faker;
    /** @var ObjectManager */
    private $manager;

    private $referencesIndex = [];

    abstract protected function loadData(ObjectManager $manager);

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->faker = Factory::create();
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->faker = Factory::create();
        $this->loadData($manager);
    }

    protected function createMany(string $className, int $count, callable $factory)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
            $entity = new $className();
            $factory($entity, $i);
            $this->manager->persist($entity);

            // store for usage later as App\Entity\ClassName_#COUNT#
            $this->addReference($className.'_'.$i, $entity);
        }
    }
}
```

I updated my BaseFixture class.

Comment: you use doctrine-fixture-bundle?

Comment: @Nobady Yes. I'm use doctrine-fixture-bundle

Comment: What is the BaseFixtures class and how do you call the loadData method?

Comment: @Jeroen I've updated my BaseFixture above.

Comment: Does dump(get_class($manager)); in the loadData function returns "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" ?

Comment: Yes. It show "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"

Comment: Strange getConnection should be a function in that case... Did you mean to add an answer?

Comment: I don't know. But when I add annotation, I don't see the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've added

```
/**
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
 */
public function loadData(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $sql = '';

    /* @var EntityManagerInterface $manager */
    $manager->getConnection()->exec($sql);

    $manager->flush();
}
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to import multi sql files in symfony 5.2 :

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

class ImportSqlFixtures extends BaseFixture
{
    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function loadData(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // Bundle to manage file and directories
        $finder = new Finder();
        $finder->in(__DIR__.'/sql');
        $finder->name('*.sql');
        $finder->files();
        $finder->sortByName();

        /* @var EntityManagerInterface $manager */
        $connection = $manager->getConnection();

        foreach ($finder as $file) {
            echo "      Importing: {$file->getBasename()} ".PHP_EOL;

            $sql = $file->getContents();
            $connection->executeQuery($sql);  // Execute native SQL

            $manager->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28227948)